How to disable Network Interface for SSH?
In my linux machine, I have 10 network interfaces available like eth0, eth0.67, eth0.70, eth0.97 etc,.
When i run the command nc 160.48.249.170 22 to check, i get like below:
root@icon:~# nc 160.48.249.170 22
SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.2

In my system, eth0.97  is having inet as 160.48.249.170. So here SSH is listening on interface eth0.97.

Similar to above, SSH is listening on all available 10 interfaces. How to disable or enable one particular interface to listen on SSH?
In /etc/ssh/sshd_config, below was the configuration
#Port 22
#AddressFamily any
#ListenAddress 0.0.0.0
#ListenAddress ::

But i changed as below to listen only one interface and restarted ssh.
#Port 22
#AddressFamily any
ListenAddress 161.49.199.18
#ListenAddress ::

But after above change also, ssh is listening on all interfaces

configure the ListenAddress for sshd to only listen to the addresses you require

Tried it, This is the snippet from /etc/ssh/sshd_config file -  #Port 22 ListenAddress 160.49.199.186 #ListenAddress ::
But its not working. Still SSH is listening on all interfaces

You probably did it wrong - or didn't restart SSHd - or something else equally unpredictable - is there a linux administrator in your organisation you can ask to help you?

I rebooted my machine after changing sshd_config file. After reboot, i see that my changes are still there, but its not working

The config you posted as a comment would stop sshd from starting - so - I don't think you did anything - do you have a linux administrator in your organisation to help you?

Earlier it was #AddressFamily any #ListenAddress 0.0.0.0, but i change to my interface 160.48.199.186. I dont have linux administrator with me.

if the answer below does not help you, check for drop-in config files (in most distributions to be found inside the directory /etc/ssh/sshd_config.d ) - maybe you have a file inside there which adds 0.0.0.0 to the ListenAddress ...

Note that in addition to sshd configuration files, most/all options can also be set on the sshd command-line, which will override sshd_config and any included snippets. So check how sshd is started and see for example the systemd service unit sets options that forces certain behavior

I would proceed as follows:
Modify your sshd configuration:

Edit the sshd configuration file, typically located at /etc/ssh/sshd_config.
Look for the option ListenAddress. By default, it's commented out (#ListenAddress).
Uncomment the line and add the IP address of your interface you want to use.

Configure your Firewall if applicable
Additionally, I would restrict SSH access using the system-firewall, I assume that you use UFW, but this should work with any firewall.

Deny all incoming traffic using sudo ufw default deny incoming (Note, that this blocks EVERYTHING, so make sure that you won't lose your connection to the server!)
Explicitly allow SSH traffic on your NIC (I assume it's eno0 for this example) sudo ufw allow OpenSSH on eno0 (Instead of OpenSSH you can also use your port, e.g. 22)

You could also tinker around with /etc/host.deny and /etc/hosts.allow but I'm not sure if you can define rules on interface level.

As I saw, that you already did step 1, and it didn't help you, I'd assume, that you didn't restart ssh correctly.
Note that there are two different services:

ssh.service
sshd.service

The "difference" is explained here.
Maybe, there's something messed up.
When you check the status of your server, you can see, since when it is running. So make sure, that your server really got restarted. (Note that I have an Alias for status to sudo systemctl status)
╭─user@host ~
╰─$ status sshd.service
● ssh.service - OpenBSD Secure Shell server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/ssh.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Thu 2024-04-18 11:42:44 CEST; 7s ago
       Docs: man:sshd(8)
             man:sshd_config(5)
    Process: 686 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/sshd -t (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 687 (sshd)
      Tasks: 1 (limit: 9255)
     Memory: 1.6M
        CPU: 63ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/ssh.service
             └─687 "sshd: /usr/sbin/sshd -D [listener] 0 of 10-100 startups"


You can also test your SSH configruation using sudo sshd -t -f /etc/ssh/sshd_config.
If there is no error, it won't complain and give no output.

Edit
I would like to refer here to @Martin's comment. It would be smart to look in /etc/ssh/sshd_config.d/ for other configuration files that might influence the behavior.
Whether the directory is taken into account can be seen from the line Include /etc/ssh/sshd_config.d/*.conf (should be at the top) in /etc/ssh/sshd_config. (This should be the default)
Note: The path can also be different.
For example, Include /etc/ssh/example/example.conf would also include this file if the line is in sshd_conf.

Hi, As you mentioned, i have done Step 1 which is configuring sshd_config file. But after that when i check sshd status using systemctl command , i get as Unit sshd.service could not be found. I tried using service sshd restart but getting as -sh: service: not found.  Hence i used sync command

Uncomment the line and add the IP address of your interface you want to use. will result in SSHd not starting at all - as far as I can tell, if you use an IP address you MUST include a port - I may be mistaken, but that doesn't happen often

Uncommented the line and now it is #Port 22 #AddressFamily any ListenAddress 160.49.199.186 #ListenAddress ::. Regarding port, it will be 22 only for ssh

@JaromandaX, thank you for the hint.
I tested it and "It works on my machine" without specifying a port. (Note, that I use for reasons port 1636 and therefore already have defined Port 1636 in my sshd_config)
But sure, this must not be true for all distros.
I'm currently on Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS

Ahh, maybe because I don't specify a Port setting

@KarmaYogi, seems something's messed up.
What is the output of ls -al /lib/systemd/system | grep -i ssh and ls -al /etc/systemd/system/ | grep -i ssh?
Also, could you please post the output of sudo systemctl show ssh -P FragmentPath and sudo systemctl show sshd -P FragmentPath?

output of ls -al /lib/systemd/system | grep -i ssh is root@icon:~# ls -al /lib/systemd/system | grep -i ssh -rw-r--r--    1 root     root           143 Apr 15 21:02 sshd.socket -rw-r--r--    1 root     root           305 Apr 15 21:02 sshd@.service -rw-r--r--    1 root     root           169 Apr 15 21:02 sshdgenkeys.service. Output of ls -al /etc/systemd/system/ | grep -i ssh is empty. For command sudo systemctl show ssh -P FragmentPath getting output as systemctl: invalid option -- 'P'.

What system are you using?
Can you please post the output of cat /etc/os-release.
It would help me to understand what Symlinks and what services should be where.

Am using custom built Linux Image 5.15. Below is the output of cat /etc/os-release. ID=team NAME="TEAM targeting performance builds." VERSION="TEAM_24" VERSION_ID=team_24 PRETTY_NAME="team targeting performance builds. TEAM_24"

@JJandke any comments ?

As I do not know TEAM_24 Linux - It's a custom build - I'm not sure, where your symlinks should be.

Were you able to fix your problem in the meantime or does it still exist?

issue still exists. I tried adding DenyUsers in sshd_config, but didnt worked. Also created /etc/host.deny file and added sshd: 160.48.249.170. But nothing is working. nc is still listening on this interface

Okay, but while it's  listening, is it also responding to incoming ssh connections or ist it denying them? Honestly, I have no clue, where the problem could be, and it's very hard for me to troubleshoot without having access to the machine. Eventually the service is just listening on those interfaces but denying all incoming requests...
